# SDI Converters from Many other Forms

Tags: video, video-quality, standards-converter, signal-processing

I need a Converter from DVI, VGA, and CVBS to SDI.

The most important thing is that this converter don't change the signals informations, I want it just to convert the signal.
Is that even possible ?

Comment: I don't think you can 'convert' something and not change it in some way. Could you try to clarify what you expect?

Comment: I want to record a video signal through a device and it takes in as input only SDI so I need a converter or a Frame Grabber that won't effect my Video signal because I want to test it.